# How to extract values with a specific data from an XML column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have a query that gave an error that i dont know exactly why gave that error. What is the problem?

```
   SELECT top 10 [ID]
      ,[EVENTCLASS]
      ,[EVENTNAME]
      ,[EVENTDATA]
      ,[EVENTDATE]
      ,[BYUSER]
      ,[IDENTIFIER]
      ,[ZONE]
      ,[ARCHIVED]
      , metadata.value('(./@Value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as CurrentEvent
FROM [dbo].[EventLog] with(nolock)
  cross apply eventdata.nodes ('/document/data[@name = ''EventStatus'']') as metadata
  where convert (date, eventdate) > '2019-04-15'
  and  metadata.value('(./@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'Recognized'
```

I have to search in Eventdata column that is an XML like this :

```
<Document ID="50f1c559-7a2a-4420-8fcb-de1e3d523c1a" Action="CREATE">
  <Data Name="EventTenant" Value="soc" Type="System.String" />
  <Data Name="TargetTenant" Value="soc" Type="System.String" />
  <Data Name="UserId" Value="519" Type="System.Int32" />
  <Data Name="EventStatus" Value="Recognized" Type="System.String" />
  <Data Name="TimeStamp" Value="2019-03-15 12:22:02.095" Type="System.String" />
  <Data Name="NextEventStatus" Value="Exported" Type="System.String" />
  <Data Name="NextEventAppId" Value="003" Type="System.String" />
  <Data Name="DocumentId" Value="50f1c559-7a2a-4420-8fcb-de1e3d523c1a,003" Type="System.String" />
</Document>
```

I want to search by EventStatus and its value.

Comment: XML is case-sensitive...if you're using XPath: `«document/data»` s/b `«Document/Data»`...and also `«@name=''EventStatus''»` s/b `«@Name='EventStatus'»`...apart from those there are some other errors are there too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shredding on nodes where `Name=EventStatus` and you use a where clause where `Value=Recognized`.

Those can be combined into one using [exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) something like this.

```
SELECT top 10 [ID]
      ,[EVENTCLASS]
      ,[EVENTNAME]
      ,[EVENTDATA]
      ,[EVENTDATE]
      ,[BYUSER]
      ,[IDENTIFIER]
      ,[ZONE]
      ,[ARCHIVED]
FROM [dbo].[EventLog]
where convert (date, eventdate) > '2019-04-15'
  and eventdata.exist('/Document/Data[@Name = "EventStatus" and @Value = "Recognized"]') = 1
```